# Web-scraping a link from web-page

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

New to web-scraping here. I basically want to extract a link from a web page into my jupyter notebook as shown in the image below :

[image]

Following is the code that I tried out:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

flipkart_url = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=" + 'acer-aspire-7-core-i5'
uClient = uReq(flipkart_url)
flipkartPage = uClient.read()
flipkart_html = bs(flipkartPage, "html.parser")

#Since I am only interested in the class "_1AtVbE col-12-12"
bigboxes = flipkart_html.findAll("div", {"class": "_1AtVbE col-12-12"})
```

Now here's the thing, I don't exactly understand what bigboxes is storing. The type of bigboxes is bs4.element.ResultSet, the length is 16.

Now if I run:

```
box = bigboxes[0]
productlink = "https://www.flipkart.com" + box.div.div.div.a['href']
```

I am getting an error. However when I run:

```
box = bigboxes[2]
productlink = "https://www.flipkart.com" + box.div.div.div.a['href']
```

I am successfully able to extract the link. Can someone please explain to me why the third element was able to read the link? I have a basic knowledge of HTML (at least I thought so) and I don't understand the layers to it. What exactly is bigboxes storing? Clearly, the HTML script shows no layers as such.

Comment: That points to the "Filters" text element off to the left and there's no link in it. If there's some data you want to get, you might want to mention that so I can write a more useful answer than this.

Comment: @ggorlen following is the website I am targetting: https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=acer-aspire-7-core-i5
I want to know how can I enter inside a product's details to scrap the reviews. I want to automate this process for 1000s of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class filter is not very specific.

The first and second elements are pointing to html nodes which do not contain the link. Thus you are getting error.

A more specific class to check could be: _13oc-S

```
bigboxes = flipkart_html.findAll("div", {"class": "_13oc-S"})
```